# Order of grid elements has no effect on the visual outcome CSS

Tags: css, css-grid

When trying to put my HTML into a grid format the elements do not change to the correct postion set and do not move at all and was wondering if there was any fix to this. I am using firefox and am using an server to edit the code and host the website. As well as this it comes up with a cautio that grid-template-area: is an unknown propiety if this makes any diffrence.

```css
.diaryNav {
    grid-area: diaryNav;
    margin-left: 0px;
    background-color: #3F3F3F;
    padding: 30px;
    margin-left: 35px;
    margin-right: 880px;
}

.banner {
    grid-area: banner;
}

.timeTable {
    grid-area: timeTable;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.diaryEntry {
    grid-area: diaryEntry;
}

.extraWork {
    background-color: #66fcf1;
    color: black;
    margin-left: 0px;
    grid-area: extraWork;
}

.refrences {
    grid-area: refrences;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.pageNav {
    gridArea: pageNav;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

#wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 0;
    grid-template-areas: "banner" "timeTable" "pageNav" "diaryNav" "diaryEntry" "extraWork" "refrences" "footer";
}
```

```html
<!doctype html><!--HTML5 doctype declaration -->
<html lang="en">
   <!--default language of the document content -->
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <!--character encoding for the document (Unicode) -->
      <title>Brandon's Learning Journal</title>
      <!--web page title -->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="normal">
      <link href="css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet /">
   </head>
   <body>
      <!--Markup all web page content inside the 'body' tags -->
      <div id="wrapper">
         <a id="top"></a>
         <!--The 'wrapper' contains all the page content-->
         <header class=banner>
            <!--The main heading for the page -->
            <h1>Welcome to my Learning journal</h1>
            <h2>
               Feel free to look around and check out the other pages avaliable
            </h2>
         </header>
         <aside class=pageNav>
            <nav class="menu">
               <!--The primary navigation for the page -->
               <ul>
                  <li><a href="">Learning Journal</a></li>
                  <li><a href="tutorial.html">Tutorial</a></li>
                  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact me</a></li>
               </ul>
            </nav>
         </aside>
         <main>
            <!--The main page content -->
            <aside class=timeTable>
               <h2>Weekly Posts</h2>
               <table class=dates border="1">
                  <tr>
                     <th>Day/time</th>
                     <th>Monday</th>
                     <th>Tuesday</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>9-10am</td>
                     <td></td>
                     <td>CI435 lecture</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>10-11am</td>
                     <td>CI401 lecture</td>
                     <td>CI435 lab </td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
            </aside>
            <aside class=diaryNav>
               <p class=menu><a href="#w1">Go to week one</a></p>
               <p class=menu><a href="#w2">Go to week two</a></p>
               <p class=menu><a href="#w3">Go to week three</a></p>
               <p class=menu><a href="#w4">Go to week four</a></p>
            </aside>
            <article class=diaryEntry>
               <diary>
                  <ul>
                     <li>
                        <a id="w1"></a>
                        <h3>Week 1: ...</h3>
                        <p>Hello </p>
                        <figure>
                           <img src="images/ssww1.png" alt=" " />
                           <figcaption>Week 1 of the website<br />
                              <small>Screenshot Brandon Bridges</small>
                           </figcaption>
                        </figure>
                        <p>I learned to:</p>
                        <ol>
                           <li>a</li>
                           <li>b</li>
                        </ol>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <a id="w2"></a>
                        <h3>Week 2: ...</h3>
                        <p>Hello </p>
                        <p>I learned to:</p>
                        <ol>
                           <li>a</li>
                           <li>b</li>
                        </ol>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <a id="w3"></a>
                        <h3>Week 3: ...</h3>
                        <p>Hello </p>
                        <p>I learned to:</p>
                        <ol>
                           <li>a</li>
                           <li>b</li>
                        </ol>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </diary>
            </article>
            <aside class=extraWork>
               <h2>My own work outside of lessons</h2>
               <p>Some reference here to my own reading and research, explaining what I have done and what I have learned from it.</p>
            </aside>
            <aside class=refrences>
               <h2>References</h2>
               <ol>
                  <li>
                     <blockquote>helo???</blockquote>
                  </li>
                  <li>...</li>
               </ol>
               <p class=menu><a href="#top">Go to top</a></p>
            </aside>
         </main>
         <!--Close main page content --> 
         <footer>
            <!--Footer content -->
            <small>&copy; 2019, author.</small>
         </footer>
      </div>
      <!--Close 'wrapper' div -->
   </body>
   <!--Close 'body' -->
</html>
<!--Close 'html' -->
```

Comment: show your html, pls

Comment: I have added it below the post Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

After fixing what @s.kuznetsov has described you should mind adding a **class** or an **id** to you `main` tag and then apply this `css` to it instead of the wrapper or however you prefer

```
#main{
          display: grid;
            grid-gap: 0;
            grid-template-areas: "timeTable diaryNav"
                                 "diaryEntry extraWork" 
                                 "refrences refrences" 
        }
```

When using `grid-area` and `grid-template-areas` you are implicitly arranging your content in a table-like form, so you specify which area goes into which cell.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I can notice is that you have the **doctype** in lowercase, change it to , the next is the **normalize**, the rel says *"normal"* which is wrong because it is a css file and it should say **"stylesheet"**. The next thing that is the problem is that it says in the ***stylesheet.css*** file in the rel it says *"stylesheet /"*, remove the space and the **/**. With that it should work

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is the missing double quotes when declaring the class in html elements. You pointed out as:

```
<aside class=diaryNav>
```

Correct like this:

```
<aside class="diaryNav">
```

And you have many items with this error!

Also, there is one error in the css, when specifying rule `grid-area: pageNav` to `.pageNav`. You indicated like this:

```
gridArea: pageNav;
```

Correct like this:

```
grid-area: pageNav;
```

And write `doctype` in uppercase. Like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```css
.diaryNav {
    grid-area: diaryNav;
    margin-left: 0px;
    background-color: #3F3F3F;
    padding: 30px;
    margin-left: 35px;
    margin-right: 880px;
}

.banner {
    grid-area: banner;
}

.timeTable {
    grid-area: timeTable;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.diaryEntry {
    grid-area: diaryEntry;
}

.extraWork {
    background-color: #66fcf1;
    color: black;
    margin-left: 0px;
    grid-area: extraWork;
}

.refrences {
    grid-area: refrences;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.pageNav {
    grid-area: pageNav;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

#wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 0;
    grid-template-areas: "banner" "timeTable" "pageNav" "diaryNav" "diaryEntry" "extraWork" "refrences" "footer";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Brandon's Learning Journal</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="normal">
      <link href="css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet /">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="wrapper">
         <a id="top"></a>
         <header class="banner">
            <h1>Welcome to my Learning journal</h1>
            <h2>
               Feel free to look around and check out the other pages avaliable
            </h2>
         </header>
         <aside class="pageNav">
            <nav class="menu">
               <ul>
                  <li><a href="">Learning Journal</a></li>
                  <li><a href="tutorial.html">Tutorial</a></li>
                  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact me</a></li>
               </ul>
            </nav>
         </aside>
         <main>
            <aside class="timeTable">
               <h2>Weekly Posts</h2>
               <table class="dates" border="1">
                  <tr>
                     <th>Day/time</th>
                     <th>Monday</th>
                     <th>Tuesday</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>9-10am</td>
                     <td></td>
                     <td>CI435 lecture</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>10-11am</td>
                     <td>CI401 lecture</td>
                     <td>CI435 lab </td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
            </aside>
            <aside class="diaryNav">
               <p class="menu"><a href="#w1">Go to week one</a></p>
               <p class="menu"><a href="#w2">Go to week two</a></p>
               <p class="menu"><a href="#w3">Go to week three</a></p>
               <p class="menu"><a href="#w4">Go to week four</a></p>
            </aside>
            <article class="diaryEntry">
               <diary>
                  <ul>
                     <li>
                        <a id="w1"></a>
                        <h3>Week 1: ...</h3>
                        <p>Hello </p>
                        <figure>
                           <img src="images/ssww1.png" alt=" " />
                           <figcaption>Week 1 of the website<br />
                              <small>Screenshot Brandon Bridges</small>
                           </figcaption>
                        </figure>
                        <p>I learned to:</p>
                        <ol>
                           <li>a</li>
                           <li>b</li>
                        </ol>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <a id="w2"></a>
                        <h3>Week 2: ...</h3>
                        <p>Hello </p>
                        <p>I learned to:</p>
                        <ol>
                           <li>a</li>
                           <li>b</li>
                        </ol>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <a id="w3"></a>
                        <h3>Week 3: ...</h3>
                        <p>Hello </p>
                        <p>I learned to:</p>
                        <ol>
                           <li>a</li>
                           <li>b</li>
                        </ol>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </diary>
            </article>
            <aside class="extraWork">
               <h2>My own work outside of lessons</h2>
               <p>Some reference here to my own reading and research, explaining what I have done and what I have learned from it.</p>
            </aside>
            <aside class="refrences">
               <h2>References</h2>
               <ol>
                  <li>
                     <blockquote>helo???</blockquote>
                  </li>
                  <li>...</li>
               </ol>
               <p class="menu"><a href="#top">Go to top</a></p>
            </aside>
         </main>
         <footer>
            <small>&copy; 2019, author.</small>
         </footer>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```